# Javascript imports / exports CORS problem

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, instance

I need to create an instance of classes from a certain javascript file which contains 3 classes and call the methods of that classes from another javascript file. Classes in main javascript file is like:

```js
function Class1(param1, param2) {
    this.openTag;
    this.closeTag;
    this.htmlTags;

    this.openTag = '<div id="' + this.elementId + '">';
    this.closeTag = '</div>';

    this.htmlTags = {
        sectionTitle: {
            openTag: '<h2 class="class1">',
            closeTag: '</h2>'
        },
        group: {
            openTag: '<div class="class2">',
            closeTag: '</div>'
        },
        table: {
            openTag: '<table class="class3">',
            closeTag: '</table>'
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

And methods like:

```js
 Class1.prototype.someName = function (index) {
    var outputHtml = '';

    var text = this.tableHeaders[index] || '';

    outputHtml += '<th>' + text + '</th>';

    return outputHtml;
}
```

How can I create an instance of these classes and call them from another javascript file or how can I use them in HTML? When I try to do ES6 imports/exports or creating new object referring to those classes it gives me this error:

`Access to script at 'file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/someName.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

&

`app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out my problem. I wasn't using `node.js`. I was trying to call the functions from another file and display them in a `HTML` file. But `CORS` policy don't let me use them. What I did is, installed [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension on VS Code.

It stars a `localhost` server and the problem solves. Because what you need is `http://`. Since when you open a HTML file, it will load the model from `file://` and that causes a problem. You can simply start the `localhost` by open a HTML file and right-click on the editor and click on `Open with Live Server`.

I used instances like `const abc = new Class();` and `abc.someMethod();`.

**Important Notes**

Do not forget to add `script` tags to your `HTML` and make sure your main `script` tag is below the others like:

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./readyFunctions.js"></script> <!-- Functions you will call -->
 <script src="./main.js"></script> <!-- js file where you call functions -->
```

The other important note is, if you are getting this kind of error even you did what I told, make sure your `script` tags don't have `type= "module"`.

You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/58312420#58312420) for other kind of solutions. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

javascript modules works best if your project was created using npm i.e you are not loading script file at the bottom of your index.html. And if you did load script at the bottom you may have to do something like this

```
<script type="module">

       import btn from './helper'

   </script>
```

Comment: Project didn't created using npm. It is just a single js file with ecmascript 5. Imports / exports is an ES6 feature.So, I don't know to call functions from another file.